# How can I run JMH with Dotty?

Tags: sbt, jmh, sbt-jmh

I'm trying to set up JMH benchmarking with a Dotty project and sbt (I'm using sbt-jmh 0.3.7) and Dotty 0.23-RC1.

I run with this cmd:

```
sbt -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true "scalajack_benchmarks/jmh:run -f 1 -t 1 -wi 5 -i 15"
```

I'm getting this error output:

```
[info] running (fork) org.openjdk.jmh.Main -f 1 -t 1 -wi 5 -i 15
[error] WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
[error] WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.openjdk.jmh.util.Utils (file:/private/var/folders/ph/ccz4n1qs62n0bn8mqdg94gsw0000gp/T/sbt_fffc0906/target/e752ff01/c82dacdf/jmh-core-1.21.jar) to field java.io.PrintStream.charOut
[error] WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.openjdk.jmh.util.Utils
[error] WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
[error] WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[error] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ERROR: Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList
[error]     at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.AbstractResourceReader.getReaders(AbstractResourceReader.java:98)
[error]     at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.BenchmarkList.find(BenchmarkList.java:122)
[error]     at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.internalRun(Runner.java:263)
[error]     at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:209)
[error]     at org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(Main.java:71)
[error] Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
```